# Are there any tools for automated penetration testing of Silverlight applications?

Tags: appsec, web-application, penetration-test, tools, silverlight

I'd like to find a tool to assist with automated penetration testing of Silverlight applications, in a similar vein to AppScan for webapps.

Specifically, I'm looking for a tool that can cope with sending requests to binary RIA service endpoints.

Do such tools exist?

Comment: Frankly I'm interested in any automated penetration testing tools (more specifically network, but I'm happy to see any perspective).  I religiously warn against automation, but I would love to be able to schedule a scan and see trending.

Comment: P.S. Core INSIGHT is something to look at, but not an answer to this question.  http://www.coresecurity.com/content/CORE-INSIGHT-Enterprise

Comment: Product recommendations are discouraged here.  Can you re-cast your question to ask about the features of a suitable tool, or something like that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Short Answer: No *(though with the speed of the web, by the time you read this things might have changed...)*

Long Answer: There are several that may be helpful, but I haven't tried them

- [WCF binary soap plugin for Burp Suite](http://www.gdssecurity.com/l/b/2009/11/19/wcf-binary-soap-plug-in-for-burp/)
- [SoapUI](http://www.soapui.org/)

Comment: +1 and accepting this answer for now as Burp Suite + WCF binary SOAP plugin looks like it supports my need (although I also have not yet tried it...).